# Lodash memoize key when the function being memoized accepts functions?

Tags: javascript, optimization, lodash, memoization

I have a large data collection that I frequently query by first applying a filter to it. I want to cache and reuse the results of the different filter functions I use because this part can be expensive. Here's a rough simulation of this:

```
const a = x => x + 1;
const b = x => x + 2;

const m = _.memoize( 
  f => (console.log('filtering data'), f(314159)),
  f => String(f)
 );

console.log(m(a));
console.log(m(b));
console.log(m(a));
console.log(m(b));
```

Here "a" and "b" would be the filter functions I want to use and "m" is acting on the same data each time.

How do I specify the key for the _.memoize function?

The above works but I'm using the string representation of the function which feels wrong. Is there a better way?

I'm worried this isn't safe when minification is applied. In my actual code, the "memoize" part is in one ES6 module, the "a" and "b" parts are in another module and the calls to "m" are in several different modules which import the "a" and "b" function. Will the string representation be stable across modules like this? Is converting to the string representation fast?

The only alternative I can think of is to create a string -> function dictionary so you would do calls like m("a") but JavaScript linters won't pick up if the name is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The above works but I'm using the string representation of the function which feels wrong.

Indeed.

> I'm worried this isn't safe when minification is applied.

No, minification is not the problem. Different functions get minified to different code.

The problem is closures:

```
const addTo = x => y => x + y
const a = addTo(1),
      b = addTo(2);
console.log(String(a) === String(b));
```

You can only reliably compare functions by their object identity. The best way would probably be to update Lodash to use an ES6 `WeakMap` that doesn't require any stringification.

As long as such is not available, you can use

```
const id = Symbol("function identity");
let count = 0;
function toMemoizeKey(fn) {
    return fn[id] || (fn[id] = ++count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain how WeakMap would help and how your snippet using "Symbol" solves this? Really happy for the tips but I'm just not following. You're right about the closure issue...just detecting the outer most function would be enough here though.

Comment: A `WeakMap` in the implementation of `_.memoize` would avoid all this stringification as you could directly use the function object as a key. The `toMemoizeKey` function is supposed to be used as the second argument in your call. It provides a simple tagging functionality, mapping every function object to a unique integer.

Comment: Thanks, looked it up: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap ... so that avoids the issue of the functions being converted to strings but will the same function be recognised if it's being included over multiple modules and when minification is involved?

Comment: @fstr What do you mean by "included over multiple modules"? A function declaration that appears multiple times in different places are different functions.

Comment: So from the question I posted, I mean I've got a single definition of function f in a file/module and several other modules want to call that via _. memoize. If I use WeakMap with _. memoize, this will work even when aggressive minification is used? And WeakMap will reference f directly instead of a string representation?

Comment: @fstr Yes, if you have only a single definition this will work regardless from where it is referenced. And yes, this is absolutely unaffected by minification.